# How can I get a Javascript Select Option Value to be Submitted to the database by Post

Tags: javascript, java, json

This is My form fields Object that create the form element with its attributes. I am trying to get the select option values from the form by document.getElementById() method as shown below **without using JQuery**

```
var model = vehicle.extend(vehicle.compare, {

fromFields:[{
    id: 'vehicle',
    label: 'Vehicle',
    name: 'vehicle',
    type: 'select',
    options: [
        {label: 'KBS999H', value:'BU'}, 
        {label: 'KBB343T', value:'LO'}, 
        {label: 'KBD342H', value:'YU'}
     ]
},{
    id: 'modelId',
    label: 'Vehicle Model',
    name: 'model',
    type: 'select',
    options: [
        {label: 'TOYOTA', value:'TT'}, 
        {label: 'VOXY', value:'VO'}, 
        {label: 'MISTUBISHI', value:'MIST'},
        {label: 'SUBARU', value:'SU'}
     ]
},{
    id: 'price',
    label: 'Price',
    name: 'price',
    type: 'number'
}]

});
```

**this is the part of the framework i am trying to submit the form**

```
    submitForm: function(){
    var me = this;

    var formValues = me.fromFields.filter(function(el){

        if (el.type == 'select' && el.options){
            //to get the selected value 
            var select = document.getElementById(el.options[name]).value;

        console.log(me.fromFields.id);

        }

        var formEl = me.getEl(el.id);
        if(formEl && formEl.value)
            return el;

    }).map(function(el){
        var formEl = me.getEl(el.id);
        return encodeURIComponent(el.name) + '=' 
            + encodeURIComponent(formEl.value);

    }).join('&');

    me.ajaxRequest.call({
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        httpUrl: me.formUrl,
        requestParams: formValues,
        responseTarget: me.responseTarget,
        updateTarget: function(resp){
            if(me.aftersubmit)
                me.aftersubmit();
        }
    });

}
```

**Encountered Error**

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
>
> var select = document.getElementById(el.options[name]).value;

Comment: Are you calling this code before the element exists on the page? Null means the element doesn't exist.

Comment: Just use the value of the select field. You don't submit the value of an option explicitly. That's for the user to choose. And the value is then assigned in the select's value ready for submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's exactly you trying to do?

You can get the value of select field like:

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');
// Selected string value.
var selected = select.value;
// Selected option element.
var selectedOptionElement = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
```